# Pop Up Search Window not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some troubles getting a search bar to work on my website. I have used Ecwid as my eCommerce and they provide a free store page if you don't have your own to use. As I was browsing it, I noticed their search bar looks pretty cool. At present, I am working between two search bar ideas and neither are working to a finished product standard. What I want is located here: https://store11298175.ecwid.com/3-in-a-Bed-Head-Teddy-Trio-p83355031 and I have made an attempt here: http://now-voyager.pagecloud.com/shoreditch-unbound The problem I am getting here is that the keyword is ending up in the wrong place in the url. The result I am getting is *shoreditch-unbound?keywords=gold#!/~/search/keywords=&offset=0&sort=relevance* however, what I need to be seeing is *shoreditch-unbound?#!/~/search/keywords=gold&offset=0&sort=relevance* Can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I have looked long and hard for a solution and keep coming up empty handed.

Comment: You need to post the code you want help with here, not at a remote site.

Comment: Post some snippet of your code. Remove the static parameters from the action. `keywords=&offset=0&sort=relevance`

Comment: my apologies, I am using the following coding to implement this on my site. <div class="search-panel hidden">
 <form method="get" action="#!/~/search/keywords=&offset=0&sort=relevance">
  <input class="text-field" type="search" name="keywords" value="" placeholder="Let us find that for you, Cookie!">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="">
  <div class="loader"></div>
 </form>
</div>

Comment: @Ritz when I use your example, the link comes back with *keywords=&offset=0&sort=relevance?keywords=purple+flower* So for some reason, when I remove the *#!/~/search/* it then places the keywords at the end of the url...

Comment: @AnthonyClifton Please [edit] your question to include the code necessary to reproduce your error, in a [mcve]. Also, you might want to read [ask], especially the bit about writing titles; the current title is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

The way the site seems to work, you can't use a regular GET form for this. Using GET will always put a `?` in your URL which won't work with your site. You'll probably need to use some Javascript that redirects your user to http://now-voyager.pagecloud.com/shoreditch-unbound#!/~/search/keywords=[keywordHere]&offset=0&sort=relevance when they submit the form.

Comment: when I use your example, it runs a query based on [keywordHere] :(

Comment: You need to replace [keywordHere] with the keyword you want to search for

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, however I want that [keywordHere] to be filled in by what ever is typed into the search bar. At present, this is not replacing the [keywordHere] with the input text.

Comment: Well yes, you'll probably have to use some Javascript like I said to insert the word into the link. For example, you could set it up so that when the search button is pressed, a function pulls the value of the search input box and then redirects the page to the correct url.